# Devise Session Controller. Custom routing on failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

Right now I'm extending the Devise sessions controller. Everything is working fine except that when the password is typed wrong or it can't find the user. it tries to redirect_to the sessions#new. I do not want that for my case I want it to redirect to a custom route because this is coming from a different view than the sessions new view. I know about `after_sign_in_path_for` but I'm not sure that is what I want because my particular case is the warden.authenticate! method. In the auth_options there is a recall hash. That is where I want to customize my route. Here is my sessions controller.

### Session Controller

```
    class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create

    super do |user|
      if params[:user][:invitation_id].present?
        invitation = Invitation.find(params[:user][:invitation_id])

        if !user.accounts.exists?(id: invitation.account.id)
          user.accounts << invitation.account
          flash[:tip_off] = "You now have access to your project \"#{invitation.account.name}\""
        else
          flash[:tip_off] = "You are already a member of #{invitation.account.name}"
        end

        cookies[:account_id] = invitation.account.id
        invitation.destroy
        user.save
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As I stated before this works fine I just need a custom routes upon failure of password or email. Right now it goes to sessions#new, that does not work for my case. Any help would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override recall value on auth_option method to redirect to another route on failure.

```
def auth_option
  { scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#another_new_path" }
end
```